# Swift 4 pop to a view controller : navigation method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

> > **Pop To viewController : Go to Previos controller**

```
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(AddSalesController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Make sure controller is exist then only perform popToViewController otherwise use popToRootController. You can get all controllers usind navigationController.viewControllers property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your controller is in the navigation stack and you can try this code.

```
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
    if controller.isKind(of: SOListScreen .self) {
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @lukas wursburger